Using state machine in Kotlin and sending updates
I've created a state machine defining it's states, events and transitions using KStateMachine. When an event is sent to the state machine, the state is changed accordingly.
Since the UI has nothing to do with the state machine, it still needs to show elements based on the current state of the state machine
In the example below, how would I notify the UI that a state from the state machine has changed?
@Singleton
class StateManager() : IStateManager {
    private var stateMachine: StateMachine? = null

    init {
        runBlocking {
            startupMachine()
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun startupMachine() {
        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
        stateMachine = createStateMachine(scope) {
            addInitialState(State.Initializing)

            addState(State.Starting) {
                transition<Event.Initializing> {
                    targetState = State.Initializing
                }
            }

            addState(State.Initializing) {
                transition<Event.Initialized> {
                    targetState = State.Initialized
                }
            }

            onStateEntry { state, _ ->
                println("Received new state of $state")
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun processEvent(event: StateEvent) {
        stateMachine!!.processEvent(event)
    }
}


Keep a StateFlow you expose as a property, collect in the UI, and update in onStateEntry?

Do you have an example? @dominicoder

See answer for an example.

You expose a StateFlow as a property, per the documentation:
class StateManager() : IStateManager {
    private val _stateFlow: MutableStateFlow(State.Default)
    val stateFlow = _stateFlow.asStateFlow()
    ...

You collect it wherever you care about it (in this case your UI), again, per the documentation
class YourUi {
   fun startCollecting() {
       myStateManager.stateFlow.collect {
           updateUiWith(it)
       }
   }
}

And you "fire events" by updating the value:
onStateEntry { state, _ ->
    println("Received new state of $state")
    _stateFlow.value = state
}


You can use flow of states, it a built-in library feature.
This is a source code:
https://github.com/KStateMachine/kstatemachine/blob/5f07bf4f850ee99630588b4bb03d24c5abac6337/kstatemachine-coroutines/src/commonMain/kotlin/ru/nsk/kstatemachine/statemachine/StateMachineFlow.kt#L95
